# [self.navigationController popToViewController:VC2 animated:NO]; crash

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

Hi I am developing an application in which I supposed to go:

1. From `UIViewController`1 to `UIViewController`2
2. From `UIViewController`2 to `UIViewController`3
3. From `UIViewController`3 to `UIViewController`4
4. From `UIViewController`4 back to `UIViewController`2

I am using `UINavigationController`. When I use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2 animated:NO];` and `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];` everything works fine.

But when I use `[self.navigationController popToViewController:VC2 animated:NO];` from `UIViewController`4 application terminates saying `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'`

Following is my code how I am popping to `UIViewController`2

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
            if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
                ViewController2 *VC2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
                [self.navigationController popToViewController:VC2 animated:NO];
            }
        }
```

When I printed navigation array it shows `UIViewController`2 in stack.
I have added `UINavigationController` from Editor->embed in->Navigation Controller

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? I tried to search for this issue but nothing is helpful

Comment: I think you haven't VC2 instacne in your UINavigationController. Maby you got 2 different instances of UIViewController2? Try to call [[self.navigationController viewControllers] indexForObject:VC2]; and [VC isKindOfClass:[UIViewController2 class]] in for-each loop to check if I am right.

Comment: You have to jump to a UIViewController that is on the navigation stack. You are trying to pop to a newly allocated navigation controller.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here you instantiate a new VC2 view controller instance, this is not the instance you have on the navigation view controller stack!

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
            ViewController2 *VC2 = [storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
```

So you have to find the right instance in

```
[[self.navigationController] viewControllers]
```

Solution 1: (as iDev said, jump to second view controller on stack, use this if you know it is the second one)

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Solution 2: (generally go back 2 level on the stack)

```
NSUInteger ownIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:ownIndex - 2] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Good answer it is perfect for my requirement.

Answer (score 9):

that is your code:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        ViewController2 *VC2 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:VC2 animated:NO];
    }
}
```

you might have already spotted that the `vc` is a kind of `ViewController2` and that is *already* in the navigation stack. the new instance, you created as `VC2` of the `ViewController2`, is *not* in the navigation stack, **it never was**.

see the exception's body:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

therefore you want to navigate back to a view controller which has not pushed into the navigation stack – that causes the crash.

you have to navigate back to a view controller which has been *already* in the stack – that is your `vc`:

```
for (UIViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this line to pop your viewcontroller to 2 nd

```
  [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```